# How to select from two tables and display only one item from 1 table and many from the second table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table user and Image table I want to select only the profile picture in the image table and in the user table  I can select 3 fields . I tried using the Inner join but I can’t see no image displayed and no error . bellow is my code

```
<?Php
$target = "image_uploads/";
$image_name = (isset($_POST['image_name']));
$query ="select * from
 tish_user inner join tish_images
 on tish_user.user_id = tish_images.user_id";
    $result= $con->prepare($query);
    $result->execute();

$table = <<<ENDHTML
<div style ="text-align:center;">
<h2>Client Review Software</h2>
<table id ="heredoc" border ="0" cellpaddinig="2" cellspacing="2" style = "width:100%"  ;
margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Ref No</th>
<th>Cell</th>
<th>Picture</th>
</tr>
ENDHTML;

while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $date_created = $row['date_created'];
        $user_id = $row['user_id'];
        $username = $row['username'];

        $image_id = $row['image_id'];

        #this is the Tannery  operator to replace a pic when an id do not have one
$photo = ($row['image_name']== null)? "me.png":$row['image_name'];
#display image 




$table .=  <<<ENDINFO
<tr>
<td><a href ="client_details.php?user_id=$user_id">$username </a></td>
<td>$image_id</td>
<td></td>
<td>c</td>
<td><img src="'.$target.$photo.'" width="100" height="100">
</td>
</tr>
ENDINFO;
}

?>
```

Comment: please provide table structure with some sample data and your expected result

Comment: @FathahRehmanP ok lets make it simple I want username from tish_user and image_name from tish_images this is the image to be displayed

Comment: If you provide create table script of both table, then it will be very useful

Comment: @FathahRehmanP http://pastebin.com/pbEui73w

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see anything wrong with the above code, so check a couple of things.

1. Can you var_dump() your query result or run your query in an editor like workbench? When you do, are there images in image_uploads that correspond to the values you are seeing in the image_name field including?
2. is image_uploads a subfolder of the folder that this php page is contained in? It may be an obvious question, but sometimes it's something simple like this.
3. Still not working? Then please post the first couple rows of the query result in your question and I'll see if I can help you further.